# Работа с файлом на удаленке

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Selenium + TestNG + Winium(Java)

На виртуальной машине, надо прогонять тесты с ПО. Но в данных тестах приходится работать с документами(если точней то excel (.xls)). 
Пример теста: тест заходит на виртуалку, открывает нужную программу, через нее сохраняет файл(.xls), и должен проверить данные в нем.

Вопрос: Как тестам работать с данными файлами? Ведь просто указать путь
`File src = new File("Путь до файла")`, не работает, ищет на моем компьютере.

Есть ли некий метод(грубо говоря), который может работать с данными по удаленке? Например,

```
File src = new File("192.168.1.1","Путь до файла")
```

И еще вопрос: можно ли работать по удаленке с файлами, через selenium/winium драйвера?

Comment: Для удаленного доступа к файлам есть протокол FTP.

Comment: При чем тут Selenium? Вы же не через браузер файл создаете.

Comment: @Alex78191, не браузер создаю. Но думал если драйвер имитирует деятельность, может он тогда и поглотить нужный мне файл?

Спасибо, а касательно FTP есть существующие методы/библиотеки)?

Comment: любой FTP сервер поставь. браузеры не предназначены для открытия xlsx файлов

Comment: Можно конечно настроить firefox для поддержки загрузки локальных  файлов через [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127849/how-to-save-binary-data-of-zip-file-in-javascript) и [конвертировать blob](https://pastebin.com/B323bkn7) в строку base64.

Comment: @Alex78191, может я поздно упомянул, но тесты планируются залить в Jenkins, чтобы он сам их запускал. Если будет запускать тесты он, все равно нужен FTP сервер?

Comment: не нужно тогда FTP использовать

Comment: @Alex78191, а можете пожалуйста объяснить работу Jenkins'a.
Просто хочу понять: когда мы его запускаем, он заходит на виртуалку(куда указали по коду), и если он там то получается и будет работать на прямую с файлами, находящимися на указанном нами компе?

Comment: @Alex78191, не увидел ответа "@sank да, Jenkins собирает вашу программу самостоятельно и исполняет тесты – Alex78191 15 часов назад". Получается Jenkins и заходит  напрямую на комп?(через драйвер или как?)

Comment: Jenkins работает на удаленном ПК и на нем же запускает тесты. Что не понятного в том, что Jenkins сам собирает программу из кода в Git репозитории? Вы использовали Jenkins?

Comment: @Alex78191, я использую и git и jenkins, но познакомился с ними только недавно. Я понимаю что дженкинс(с мавеном) собирает сборку и запускает тесты. Я хотел уточнить как работает Jenkins.

Comment: Дома или на работе используешь?

Comment: @Alex78191, на работе и дома стараюсь смотреть.
На работе были уже автотесты для сайта, поэтому я их только обновил(обновляю).
Теперь нужны тесты для программы, ищу всю информацию.

Answer (score -1):

Всё работает (с) Но только если шары доступны из ОС т.е. бежим в коммандер, проверяем что файл доступен и тупо копируем путь до файлика

На винде не забываем экранировать слешики

```
new File("\\\\serverGolihKotov\\fotki\\goliekoti\\fufufu.jpg")
```

Ибо ява будет его получать средствами api ОС

Comment: вот так как раз он ищет на моем компе, а нужно чтобы искал на виртуалке.
(Это и проверено, сначала тесты у себя писал и все работало).

Comment: Надо по порядку (с) "Виртуалка" это виртуализированный пк или ява-машина? Если первое то какие ОС на хосте и виртуалке? Расшарен ли файл каким-либо образом по сети и доступен ли он с хоста?

Comment: Не уточнял на чем, скорее всего какая-то стандартная через оракл(виртуальный ПК).

И там и там винда 7 стоит.

Файл сохраняется на виртуалке,и на ней же я и хотел прогонять все тесты, не перекидывая данный файл(ы) на мой комп.

Возможно есть некие ограничения на копирование файлов, но мне не нужно их копировать, мне просто нужно их прочитать.

Comment: Ну так если у вас виртуальный ПК то корректно общаться вы с ним можете только как с другим ПК в сети - т.е. через сетевые шары например. Это простой путь. Сложный путь - виртуальный ПК может быть развернут не на образе диска а на разделе физического диска, при этом, хост может иметь доступ ко всем файлам на этом разделе но возможны конфликты доступа. Костыльный путь - многие средства виртуализации предоставляют разные реализации т.н. shared folders т.е. совместного доступа к файлам, но реализация зависит от вендора.

Comment: спасибо, попробую посмотреть.

Comment: Насчет шаров/расшаривания папок - не подходит, так как хочу чтобы тесты прогонялись только на удаленке, и запускались не с моего компьютера а с Jenkins.

Вообщем-то есть и такой вопрос(вдруг есть опыт): Если залить тесты на Jenkins, он же по идеи будет работать с файлами напрямую? Я имею ввиду он же вроде "заходит", на указанный адрес , при прогоне тестов?

Comment: @sank да, Jenkins собирает вашу программу самостоятельно и исполняет тесты